# dataframe get 2 rows with different values

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to query two rows with different values in the same column.

| name | age |
| --- | --- |
| Martin | 28 |
| Josh | 37 |
| Peter | 24 |
| Claire | 57 |

```
df = pd.read_csv('names.csv')
df.query('name.str.contains("Martin") & name.str.contains("Claire")')
```

Now i expect to see the two rows where Claire an Martin are in. But if i delete Claire the query will return only Martin. The query should only return if both values are true an give me both rows as a result.

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Martin', 'Josh', 'Peter', 'Claire'],
                  'age':[28, 37, 24, 57]})

new_df = df[df.name.isin(['Claire', 'Martin'])]
```

This gives

```
     name  age
0  Martin   28
3  Claire   57
```

Comment: I want to use str.contains or anythin similar. Because i want to get also names like "Martine".

Comment: df[df['name'].str.contains('martin')]

Comment: The Version with isin works not like i expect. if i delete "Martin" it will show only "Claire". Thats not correct. It should be only true if both names in the dataframe.